# Ninject bind only when injected into IFactory.Create() method

Tags: ninject, ninject-extensions

I have a `Foo` class that derives from `IFoo` and then an `IFooFactory` that I setup via the [Ninject Factory Extensions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki) method:

```
Bind<IFooFactory>().ToFactory()
```

I then want to make sure any caller classes get an `IFoo` instance via `IFooFactory.Create()` rather than just ask for an `IFoo` in the constructor.

I have tried to create a binding like so:

```
Bind<IFoo>.To<Foo>
          .WhenInjectedInto<IFooFactory>();
```

Which I then later call `fooFactory.Create()` on. Unfortunately Ninject isn't happy with the binding and throws a "No matching bindings are available.." exception.

I am also running into the same issue when I have a `Foo(string str)` constructor whose string dependency is passed in to the factory method via `IFooFactory.Create(string str)`.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you are binding IFoo wrong. You have to do:

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
```

to make `fooFactory.Create()` know how to resolve `IFoo`. As it is now, `IFoo` will only get resolved when injected into IFooFactory, and that instance is autogenerated by the factory extension (I'm not even sure you can use `WhenInjectedInto` on interfaces).

If you only want to be able to resolve `IFoo`:s from the factory, you could use named bindings:

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().Named("Foo");
```

The factory extension has a convention that if your factory method looks like this:

```
public interface IFooFactory 
{
    IFoo GetFoo();
}
```

it will use whatever follows "Get" as the name when resolving the binding. In this case "Foo".